# how to shift elements in an array with brute-force java

Tags: java, arrays

This was an interview question. So you have an input char array looks like this:

```
char[] input = "Hello     world!   ".toCharArray();
```

The task is to develop a method to take the char array as input and move the extra whitespaces to the end of the array without using any built in method provided by java and without deleting any elements from the array. The expected output:

```
"Hello world!       ".toCharArray();
```

As you can see there can be extra white spaces in the input which should be moved to the end of the array. My attempt:

```
public char[] moveWhiteSpaces(char[] inArr){
    for(int i = 0; i<inArr.length; i++){
        String currChar = String.valueOf(inArr[i]);
        while(currChar.equals(" ")){
            inArr[i] = inArr[i+1];
        }
    {
    return inArr;
}
```

which is not working. So how can I move the extra white spaces to the end without deleting them?
Input: `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', ' ', ' ',]`
Output:`['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '! ', ' ', ' ',' ', ' ']`

Comment: so if the input is like `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '! ', ' ', ' ',]` then the expected output is: `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '! ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']`

Comment: In your actual code you have an infinite loop calling `while(currChar.equals(" "))`... Add some traces in your loops to help you figure what's happening...

Comment: All Whitespace characters (0x09, 0x20, U200 etc., see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode for a full list) or only the space 0x20 character?

Comment: This problem is not well defined since it's not clear which spaces should be eliminated and which not. For example, what if the sentence ended in `?` or `.` instead of `!`? Would you still eliminate the spaces before the `?` and `.`.

Comment: I think the idea is when there is more than one white space between words, the extra spaces should be moved to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one `for-loop`:

```
static char[] moveWhiteSpaces(char[] input){
    char[] result = new char[input.length];
    int _char = 0, space = input.length-1;
    boolean first_occur = true, first_char = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
        char c = input[i]; 
        if(c != ' '){
          result[_char++] = c;
          first_char = true;
        }else if (c == ' ' && first_occur && first_char){
          result[_char++] = c;
          first_occur = false;
        }else{
            result[space--] = c; 
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Test

```
char[] input = "Hello     world!   Hello     world!   hahah hohohoh hehehe     random! ! ! :)".toCharArray();
System.out.println(moveWhiteSpaces(input));
```

### Result

```
Hello world! Hello world! hahah hohohoh hehehe random! ! ! :)
```

Comment: this also works well @Yahya, so +1. I accepted Ralf Renz's answer because his solution moves the white spaces from the beginning of the array as well if there is any.

Comment: @sticky_elbows No worries.. however, I just added an extra boolean to cover the spaces at the beginning.... So this is still in one for loop!

Answer (score 1):

The ! is needs special treatment. But then:

```
private static void moveSpaces(char[] input) {
    int newPos = 0;
    for (int oldPos = 0; oldPos < input.length; oldPos++) {
        if ((input[oldPos] == '!') && (input[oldPos - 1] == ' ')) {
            input[newPos - 1] = '!';
        } else if (input[oldPos] != ' ') {
            input[newPos] = input[oldPos];
            newPos++;
        } else if ((oldPos > 0) && (input[oldPos - 1] != ' ')) {
            input[newPos] = input[oldPos];
            newPos++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = newPos; i < input.length; i++) {
        input[i] = ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: The special case for ! should check if it is the first char or this implementation will produce an exception (array index out of bounds).

Comment: we can't base it on a character such as '!', it could have been anything. The idea is if there are more than one whitespace between two words, then move the extra whitespaces to the end of the array.

Comment: In the example between words one space was left and between word and '!' no space was left. If it could have been anything you must specify it.

Comment: Thanks. In that case just remove the first if in my solution.

Comment: This solution not only moves the extra spaces between the words but also the ones at the beginning of the array if there is any. I just tried it with different inputs and it works with all of them. Well done and thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
 String t = "Hello      World    !";
        String s = "";
        int c=0;
        for(int i=0;i<t.length();i++)
        {
            String s1 = String.valueOf(t.charAt(i));
            if(s1.equals(" "))
            {
                if( String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length()-1)).equals(" ")) {
                c++;
            }
            else 
            {
                s=s+s1;
            }
            }
            else 
            {
                s=s+s1;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<c;i++)
        {
            s=s+" ";
        }
```

Comment: Athira, I think the idea is when there is more than one white space between words, the extra spaces should be moved to the end

Comment: That will remove every whitespace to the end

Comment: So do you need one space between words?

Comment: @Athira yes one white space should remain between words and only the extra ones should be moved to the end

Answer (score 1):

Instead of moving chars into just one Array you can do something like this:

```
public char[] moveWhiteSpaces(char[] inArr){
    // Prepare an array for your result
    char[] result = new char[inArr.length];
    // Counter on the characters already added into the result 
    int filled = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < inArr.length; i++){
        char c = inArr[i];
        // Add the char to the result if it is not a space or if the last added char was a space 
        if(c != ' ' || (filled > 0 && result[filled-1] != ' ')){
            result[filled++] = c;
        }
    }
    // Complete the result with missing spaces
    while(filled < inArr.length) {
        result[filled++] = ' ';
    }
    return result;
}
```

This will return :

> `"Hello world !         "`

It's sometime easier, and more readable, to create intermediate objects/variables, in this case the `char[] result`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to avoid using `StringBuilder`.

```
public static char[] moveWhiteSpaces(char[] arr) {
    char[] res = fill(new char[arr.length], ' ');

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (isAlphabetic(arr[i]))
            res[j++] = arr[i];
        else if (isWhitespace(arr[i])) {
            if (i > 0 && !isWhitespace(res[j - 1]))
                res[j++] = arr[i];
        } else
            res[j == 0 ? j++ : j - 1] = arr[i];
    }

    return res;
}

private static char[] fill(char[] arr, char ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = ch;
    return arr;
}

private static boolean isAlphabetic(char ch) {
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        return true;
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
        return true;
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        return true;
    return false;
}

private static boolean isWhitespace(char ch) {
    return ch == ' ' || ch == '\t';
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.fil()` and `Character.isWhitespace()` may fall into the built in methods category and the OP is not allowed to use that...

Comment: I think that OP talks about smth. like `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.normalizeSpace(".....")`. `String.valueOf()` or `equals()` are also **built-in** functions.

Comment: I think @Nirekin is right, otherwise it would be a piece if cake!

Comment: OK, fixed with custom implementation :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] input = "Hello     world!   ".toCharArray();
    char[] output = new char[input.length];
    int count =0;
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=input.length-2;i++) {
        if(input[i] == input[i+1]  && input[i] == ' ') {
            count++;
        }else {

            output[k] = input[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    output[k] = input[input.length-1];//assigning the last variable
    for(int j=0;j<count;j++) {
        output[++k] = ' '; // adding the spaces to the end
    }
    ArrayList<Character> c = new ArrayList<>() ;//Arraylist is just to print your answer
    //in a meaningful way

    for(int i=0;i<output.length-1;i++) {
        //System.out.println(output[i]);
        c.add(output[i]);

    }
    System.out.println(c);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working in a similar answer as @Nirekin working directly with chars.

```
public char[] moveWhiteSpaces(char[] inArr){
    char[] output = new char[inArr.length];
    boolean lastCharWhiteSpace = false;
    int lastIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<inArr.length; i++){
        char currChar = inArr[i];
        if (' ' == currChar) {
            if (!lastCharWhiteSpace) {
                output[lastIndex] = currChar;
                lastIndex++;
            } 
            lastCharWhiteSpace = true;
        } else {
            output[lastIndex] = currChar;
            lastIndex++;
            lastCharWhiteSpace = false;
        }
    }

    for(int i = lastIndex; i<output.length; i++) {
        output[i] = ' ';
    }

    return output;
}
```